# Abstract factory pattern relies on object composition?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

While i was going through the book [Head first design pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) i found that "Abstract factory relies on object composition: object creation is implemented in methods exposed in the factory interface" in the abstract factory chapter. My doubt here is how come Abstract factory relies on object composition?

if i will take the example in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#Java) then GUIFactory is an interface and WinFactory implements GUIFactory. Then how Abstract factory uses composition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, how does the abstract factory _not_ rely on composition? It doesn't say 'uses', but relies. Which it does, that's what the whole pattern is about: abstracting composition.

Comment: @Creynders can you explain your point with some example. Thanks!!!

Comment: To follow the wikipedia example: Winfactory composes a WinButton, OSXFactory composes a OSXButton. These are the concrete factories that implement the abstract factory interface.

Comment: @Creynders Are you saying simply return new WinButton(); is object composition?

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't explain myself any better and probably added to the confusion. Retry: see my answer

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean that the abstract factory describes the composition for the client and in that sense relies on object composition.

To take another example, the abstract factory `BodyCreator` defines the methods `createArm`, `createLeg`, `createHead` etc. Concrete factories could be `DinosaurCreator` and `HumanCreator`. They produce all elements to create a composite "body", so that a client can call those various methods to compose one, but it doesn't need to know what type of body it exactly *is* composing. Just as in the wikipedia example GUIFactory describes what elements the GUI is composed of.

To make it more clear they should've added some more methods IMO:
`CheckBox createCheckBox()`, `TextField createTextField()` etc.

But, yeah, maybe 'relies' wasn't the best choice of words.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a blanket statement like

> Abstract Factory *relies* on object composition

is not accurate.  In this case, my sense is that this is a lazy or overly-broad use of the term `object composition` when defining `Abstract Factory`.

Wikipedia's entry for Object Composition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition is helpful here when it indicates:

> In computer science, object composition [...] is a way to combine
>   simple objects or data types into more complex ones.

Is there anything which indicates that an Abstract Factory / Factory / Factory Method cannot return simple objects or data types?

This is a rhetorical question (I think).  I can't find anything.

Comment: this statement is not mine. I found the stmt in the aforementioned book which i could not understand. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not contradicting you. I saw where you sourced that statment from and I share with you some 'confusion' about whether this statement is accurate.  I think **you make a fine point** and I'm just trying to provide some evidence to further that point.

Comment: BTW -- the Wikipedia entry for `Abstract Factory` contains the exact same phrase.  I wonder who copied whom?

Comment: @Trying Head First uses the Pizza example; a pizza is composed of dough, sauce, etc. Abstract Factory clearly is used when you have *families of products*, whereas Factory Method is a single method (albeit for an object that could be a composition). Abstract Factories' methods are going to be called for each product that "compose" the family. The GoF example is a GUI widget family, that varies by operating system. GUIs are *composed* of widgets (buttons, text areas, etc.).

Comment: @DavidTansey The Wikipedia entry cites the Head First book for that particular passage, so it's pretty clear it's the source.